# iOS - Reset a UITabBarController / UIViewController state after logout

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

After my user logout from my app, the login screen has to be shown to allow another login.

The user may change, so I will have to present the main screen again. Above there is a code that's working like mine:

```
// MainScreenViewController.swift
func onLogoutButtonTouch(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    mainViewController.present(loginViewController, animated: true, completion: {completed in
        mainViewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    })
}

// LoginViewController.swift
func onLoginSuccess() {
    loginViewController.present(mainViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

#### The problem

After my main screen is shown **after a re-login**, the last state of the `mainViewController` seems to be unchanged, with other user's data, and I don't want that.

**Is there a way to completely reset the mainViewController's state to avoid showing the last login information?**

Answer (score 0):

You need new clean storyboard init and present it over old one. Init storyboard from with nib name then instantiate initial viewController and present it.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `loginViewController` is alive when you dismiss the `mainViewController`.

You can instantiate a new loginViewController using the current storyboard and then present it like following:

```
let loginVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "`your view controller storyboard ID here`")
mainViewController.present(loginVC, animated: true, completion: {completed in
    mainViewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
})
```

Or use delegate pattern for resetting the login VC(if it's already alive). introduce a method called `reset` for example, and call it on the VC that logs out the user.

```
protocol LogoutListener {
    func resetLoginPage()
}

// LoginViewController.swift
func onLoginSuccess() {
    mainViewController.logoutListener = self
    loginViewController.present(mainViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

// MainScreenViewController.swift
func onLogoutButtonTouch(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    logoutListener?.resetLoginPage()
    mainViewController.present(loginViewController, animated: true, completion: {completed in
        mainViewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
})
}
```

Comment: Turns out that a simple `self.dismiss` on the main controller resolved this problem.